# How to get documents with specific value from an aggregation in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Let's say I have this documents:

document 1:

```
_id:"1"
name:"Item 1"
quantity:1
min:3
alert:"Yes"
```

document 2:

```
_id:"2"
name:"Item 2"
quantity:12
min:5
alert:"No"
```

How can I get just the documents with the alert value "Yes", excluding the documents with the alert value "No"?

Those documents I got it from some aggregations:

```
[
  {
    '$group': {
      '_id': '$id', 
      'name': {
        '$first': '$name'
      }, 
      'sum_quantity': {
        '$sum': '$quantity'
      }, 
      'alertMin': {
        '$first': '$alertMin'
      }
    }
  }, {
    '$project': {
      '_id': '$_id', 
      'name': '$name', 
      'quantity': '$sum_quantity', 
      'minimum': '$alertMin', 
      'alert': {
        '$cond': [
          {
            '$lte': [
              '$sum_quantity', '$alertMin'
            ]
          }, 'Yes', 'No'
        ]
      }
    }
  }
]
```

I expect the following result:

```
_id:"1"
name:"Item 1"
quantity:1
min:3
alert:"Yes"
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a `$match` stage at the end of your `aggregation` pipeline(or wherever you want the match) , and it will give you the desired result.

```
{
    $match : {
        alert : "yes"
    }
}
```

Read more about [$match here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a single pipeline stage $match. You don't need to use any other stage for that.

Try as below:

```
 db.collection.aggregate([
     {
        $match: {
            alert: "Yes"
        }       
     }
 ])
```